How to run custom regression in bigquery dataframes/bigframes (using remote functions)
I am unsure on how to run a custom regression (using the pyfixest package) with several columns using bigquery dataframes and append the regression residual as a new column. I can't figure out how to pass the full dataframe to a remote functions. A previous answer suggested using bpd.Series but this does not work. Furthermore, the pyfixest function requires a pandas dataframe as input.
I am using the following remote function. This function converts the bpd.Series into a bpd.DataFrame and then into a pandas df.
@bpd.remote_function(bpd.Series, int, reuse=False, packages=["pyfixest","pandas"])
def get_residuals(input_df):
    import pyfixest as pf
    import pandas as pd
    
    input_df = input_df.to_frame().to_pandas()

    m1 = pf.feols("spotify_streams ~ song_age_days | isrc", data=input_df)
    return m1.resid()

    #return input_df["spotify_streams"]

I am then applying this function to the original dataframe (which has columns 'isrc', 'spotify_streams', 'song_age_days')
df = bpd.read_gbq(sql, use_cache = False) #Get the data here, works fine.

df["residual"] = df[
    ["spotify_streams","song_age_days","isrc"]
].apply(get_residuals, axis=1)

But then it fails with
NameError: `song_age_days` is not present in the dataset or evaluation context.

I have also tried using just input_df = input_df.to_pandas() but then it fails with
 File \"<ipython-input-62-316cc1e96dfb>\", line 9, in get_residuals\n  File \"/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py\", line 6204, in __getattr__\n    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)\nAttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_pandas'\n"}
.

even though bpd.Series should have a .to_pandas() command.

I notice two things that need clarification:

Currently the BigFrames DataFrame.apply (see code samples) can accept functions that take in scalars, or the entire row as a pandas Series, but not an entire DataFrame.

"pandas" is specified in the packages argument, which suggests that the function body makes use of pandas methods, But to_pandas is not a pandas method, it is a bigframes method.


The main motivation of BigFrames remote_function is to utilize the distributed parallelism of the BigQuery and Google Cloud, where massive number of rows can be grouped and processed in independent small batches in parallel.
This use case is different though. It seems pf.feols needs to process the entire DataFrame together to compute the correlations.  If the data is small enough to fit in single machine memory, did we consider something like the following (without using remote function)?
df = bpd.read_gbq(sql, use_cache = False) #Get the data here, works fine.
input_df = df[["spotify_streams","song_age_days","isrc"]].to_pandas()
m1 = pf.feols("spotify_streams ~ song_age_days | isrc",data=input_df)
df["residual"] = bpd.read_pandas(m1.resid())

